# Netlogo - make patches smaller to display clearly all agents ' locations clustered in a small area

Tags: coordinates, netlogo, patch, gridworld

I am modelling delivery system of a city. the delivery branch agent's location is based on the real world coordinates. How can I make a smaller netlogo world that can clearly display all the agents in a defined area (min-x: 113.783131, max-x: 114.42618; min-y: 22.476584, max-y: 22.809712)? The current netlogo world is simply too big to make each agents visible (they all clustered in a small point)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, but are you aware of the settings in the main menu bar on the interface tab? If all the turtles are only on a few patches, then you can reduce the number of patches and increase the size of each patch. The only problem is if you are using patches for something as there won't be much differentiation.

Comment: the problem is that the origin has to be (0,0) incorporated no matter in the center or corner. the city i am modelling is far from this point. I have no idea how to skip the origin (0,0) when defining the boundary of netlogo world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is write a function that rescales your x and y coordinates into the NetLogo range. Then simply call that function whenever you refer to real world coordinates. See below for functions that are independent of the number of patches in your world. You may want to fiddle with the maximums and minimums in the functions if you want to get closer to or further away from the edge. Also, I would add an error check (so the function prints a meaningful message if you accidentally try to ask for coordinates outside your predefined max and min).

Run the testme to see what it does.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  [ setxy fix-x 113.8 fix-y 22.6 ]
  create-turtles 1
  [ setxy fix-x 114.49 fix-y 22.8 ]
end

to-report fix-x [#x]
  let minx 113.5
  let maxx 114.5
  report ((#x - minx) / (maxx - minx)) * (max-pxcor - min-pxcor) + min-pxcor
end

to-report fix-y [#y]
  let miny 22.45
  let maxy 22.82
  report ((#y - miny) / (maxy - miny)) * (max-pycor - min-pycor) + min-pycor
end
```

UPDATE from comments: If you actually have a GIS dataset, simply load that into NetLogo using the GIS extension and set the envelope. The world will adjust.

Comment: I need to load the GIS shape file as well. In such case, I need to get the "set-world-envelope" as the newly converted world boundary?

Comment: why can netlogo be more natural to support a user defined boundary of the world. I cannot understand why the origin must be (0, 0).

Comment: yes, you need to set the world envelope appropriately. You need to think of GIS coordinates and patch coordinates as two SEPARATE systems. You can import the GIS to set up buildings or whatever at appropriate locations, but once you have created them as turtles, all your logic should deal with them without mentioning GIS ever again. You may not need patches at all. You simply have your trucks move to their next location based on turtle positions.

Comment: But if you are using a GIS file, you don't need to do these functions - just use the GIS import functions directly. Your question did not say anything about GIS

Comment: many thanks. I still feel reluctant to apply a separate function to convert the real GPS coordinates into another man-made coordinates which might be less accurate. In the later of my modelling, I also need to compute the great circle distance based on the real coordinates of agents. I really just want to define a netlogo world to be as small as a city. is it feasible to do so given the current settings in Netlogo?

Comment: this was my point - if you are using GIS, you don't need the separate functions. Just use the GIS extension to import everything you want from the GIS shapefile to create your world with agents at the correct locations. Try it and then come back with a specific problem.